# confuse in fs.watch() callback function in node.js

Tags: node.js, fs

```
fs.watch('./tmp', {encoding: 'buffer'}, (eventType, filename) => {
  if (filename)
    console.log(filename);
    // Prints: <Buffer ...>
});
```

it is copy from [node.js file system 's  Class: fs.FSWatcher](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html)  documentation

documentation describe **eventType** is **string** type and it can be **'change'** or **'rename'**
so i write code like bellow

```
fs.watch('./public/dir',function('change','xx.txt'){
    console.log('file changed');
});
```

but it **SyntaxError: Unexpected string**

i don't understand what is **eventType** and **filename**

plz describe what is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The listener callback gets two arguments (eventType, filename). eventType is either 'rename' or 'change'.

Filename is the name of the file which triggered the event. from docs. 
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener

eventType, filename <- it just callback variables from listener.

To fix you need to do like this.

```
fs.watch('./public/dir',function(typeOfEvent, nameOfFile){
    console.log(typeOfEvent);
    console.log(nameOfFile);
});
```

Hope this helps.